# Higher High above EMA and lower low below EMA / Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am stuck at drawing higher highs above an ema and lower lows below the ema, using a simple code but at length its always stuck at a simple ent while my input is a series bool.

Candle closes above Ema, higher high starts till candle closes below ema, in that case lower low starts. any new high break starts fresh higher highs and any new lower low break stars a new lower low.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Highest High, Lowest Low EMA', shorttitle='HHLL EMA', overlay=true)
`ema = ta.ema(close, 20)`


aboveema = close > ema
belowema = close < ema


// Define
maPer = input(20)
topSrc = input(high)
botSrc = input(low)


// Top & Bot
top = ta.highest(topSrc, aboveema)
bot = ta.lowest(botSrc, belowema)

// Plot
plot(top, 'Highest Band', color.new(#00ff00, 0))
plot(bot, 'Lowest Band', color.new(#ff0000, 0))
plot(ta.ema(close, maPer), 'Moving Average', color.new(#00ffff, 0))
```

Length is always taken as candle bars back, have not been able to set a base condition of checking only current price above ema period or current price below ema.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved with GetHighestSince and GetLowestSince.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).